# Would we be able to see a Space craft transit in Lunar orbit?

Tags: the-moon, orbit, spacecraft, apollo-program, telescope

If a Apollo type Moon mission happened today would we be able to see it transit in Lunar orbit? I know we can't see the Landing sites of the Apollo but could we see the Command Module and its shadow orbiting the moon?

Comment: The Apollo CSM is not large enough to see from Earth, see https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27831/observing-a-lunar-lander-by-telescope/27840#27840

Comment: I knew apollo wasnt big enough to see on the surface but wasnt sure about when its away from the glare of the surface and the fact it has a Shiny surface itself. Hopefully next moon mission has a bigger CSM :) Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 5):

Let's assume you are not only looking with your eyes, but Hubble Space Telescope. HST has a resolution of about 0.05 arcseconds, or 2.424068e-7 radians. The Moon is about 384,400 km. That comes to be about 100m, just to see it as a resolved dot.

Now, one could theoretically see an unresolved dot that is smaller, but it would be extremely difficult with a noisy background like the Moon present.

What would be more likely is if a major propulsive event happened that wasn't behind the moon, it might be able to be seen. Still, that isn't very likely.

Comment: This certainly doesn't change your conclusion a lot, but the VLT is doing amazing things these days: https://gizmodo.com/new-super-crisp-images-of-neptune-show-how-far-our-tele-182768347 (I've just asked [How did VLT's adaptive optics obtain this resolution for Neptune? Is it really working in visible wavelengths?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/26989/7982))